# Centering contents horizontally in \halign

Tags: tables, plain-tex

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\catcode`\@=11

\pageheight 23mm
\pagewidth 67mm
\hoffset -1in
\voffset -1in
\advance\hoffset 2mm
\hsize 63mm
\vsize 23mm
\topskip\z@
\baselineskip 17.5\p@

\abovedisplayskip\z@
\abovedisplayshortskip\z@
\belowdisplayskip\z@
\belowdisplayshortskip\z@

\def\@textmode{mode=harf;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig}
\font\fourteenbf="MinionPro-BoldCapt.otf:\@textmode" at 14\p@

\fourteenbf

\def\N{\vrule width 2\p@}
\def\n{\vrule width 1\p@}
\def\E#1{\hbox to 8mm {\hss#1\strut\hss}}
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
    \vrule height.7\baselineskip depth.3\baselineskip width\z@}


$$
%
\tabskip\z@
\vbox{\halign{%
    \N \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n &%
        \E{#}\n & \E{#}\N \cr
    \noalign{\hrule height 2\p@}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & Ø \cr%
    \noalign{\hrule height 1\p@}
    & & & & & & \cr
    \noalign{\hrule height 2\p@}
}}
%
$$

\bye
```

Please look at the MWE. The numbers are not centered in their cells.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is it possible to center the whole table verrtically on the page?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: you could have made a test file not requiring non standard fonts, to make it easier for people to test answers.

Comment: OK, sorry, I have forgotten to delete these lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the white space you are adding in the table cells.

[image]

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\catcode`\@=11

\pageheight 23mm
\pagewidth 67mm
\hoffset -1in
\voffset -1in
\advance\hoffset 2mm
\hsize 63mm
\vsize 23mm
\topskip\z@
\baselineskip 17.5\p@

\abovedisplayskip\z@
\abovedisplayshortskip\z@
\belowdisplayskip\z@
\belowdisplayshortskip\z@

\def\@textmode{}%mode=harf;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig}
%\font\fourteenbf="MinionPro-BoldCapt.otf:\@textmode" at 14\p@
\let\fourteenbf\relax

\fourteenbf

\def\N{\vrule width 2\p@}
\def\n{\vrule width 1\p@}
\def\E#1{\hbox to 8mm {\unskip\hss\ignorespaces#1\unskip\strut\hss\ignorespaces}}
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
    \vrule height.7\baselineskip depth.3\baselineskip width\z@}


$$
%
\tabskip\z@
\vbox{\halign{%
    \N \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n & \E{#}\n &%
        \E{#}\n & \E{#}\N \cr
    \noalign{\hrule height 2\p@}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & Ø \cr%
    \noalign{\hrule height 1\p@}
    & & & & & & \cr
    \noalign{\hrule height 2\p@}
}}
%
$$

\bye
```